# sizing voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-dissipation, dimensions

I am to size a 3v3 voltage regulator,

It gets at its input 12VDC maximum. And the load can consume up to 150 mA (few leds, 20 NMOS control, ADC control, microntroler supply...) and ambient temperature can reach 70°C.

I have to be surface and cost efficient in my choice.

I'm struggling with chosing the regulator because I don't know weither the regulators I found are underdimensioned or overdimensioned.

I found those regulators:

[MC33375](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/308/MC33375-D-37871.pdf) /
[ldk320](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/389/ldk320-974193.pdf) /
[MCP1702](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/268/22008a-53656.pdf)

What do you think of them ? On some of the datasheet there are formulas but I didn't understand how to use them, as the RthA can vary depending temperature and manufacturers usually indicate its value for TA = 25°C (and not 70°C)

Thank you for your help

Comment: 12 V - 3.3 V = 8.7 v drop, at 150 mA makes 1.3 W. The regulator needs to be able to dissipate this power **and** the heat must be able to leave the IC. The 3 regulators you selected are **very small** SMD types and these have a **very high thermal resistance** meaning the heat cannot leave the chip easily. You would be much better off choosing a regulator in a larger package (for example a TO220 or similar size) and even then it will need some cooling, that means a large copper plate and/or a heatsink. If that is a problem, use a **switched** regulator (module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be an answer, but there was no other way to add a photo.

You may not ask for product recommendations in EE SE, but since you're a new user I will help you with the right search terms, but I'll not indicate any product.

I agree with @Bimpelrekkie, this is not a job for a linear regulator, since the thermal dissipation would be critical. Try a switching regulator, which is a more modern solution.

Search for "3.3V Step-Down Voltage Regulator module", or "3.3V buck voltage converter module" and you will find ready to use modules like this:
[image: converter module]

If you need to build the converter yourself, do the same search without the word "module" and you'll find indications of IC's that could be used to build circuits like this.